# JavaScript Closure. How does JS engine choose Closure Variables?

Tags: javascript, closures, ecmascript-5

This is the code example of JS Closure concept.

```
 function buildFunctions() {
        var arr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            arr.push((function(j) {
                return function() {
                    console.log(j);
                }
            }(i)));
        }
        return arr;
    }
    var fn = buildFunctions();
    fn[0]();
    fn[1]();
    fn[2]();
```

In this code i know when the loops starts to run and for each 'i' value(for each IIFE) new execution context with variables j=1,2,3 will be created respectively in JS engine. So when the loops finishes, the three returned functions from the 3 IIFE will sit in the var arr and the execution context of respective IIFE's will be gone but still having their variable environment with j=1,2,3 in the closure. So, now the arr will have

```
  var arr = [function{console.log(j)},function{console.log(j)},function{console.log(j)}]
```

My question is how the invoking of these functions in the array, `fn[0]()` picks j=0, `fn[1]()` picks j=1, `fn[2]()` picks j=2 from the closure respectively.?

If something is wrong in my understanding please help me...

Comment: Each closure is a separate object, and has access to exactly the `y` variable that is in its scope. Notice there are multiple `y` variables (with the different values) in multiple scopes (that were created by each invocation of that IEFE).

Comment: @Bergi Can I just think each round of that push create a container( the closure) in the world that .push get called and put all local variables into it and pass a reference of that container to the function get pushed?

Comment: Yes, but the *scope* (of the IIFE) is the container and the function (with the reference) is what is called "closure".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when the loops finishes […] the execution context of respective IIFE's will be gone

Well, they're not gone - that's the [point of closures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572).
Each closure keeps the context it was created in alive - so each of your functions has a reference to their variable `j` from the *respective scope*, with the respective value.

Answer (score 1):

The function logs the value of `j`.

The value of `j` is the value passed as an argument to the outer anonymous function.

That is specified when that function is called (immediately) as the value of `i`.

`i` only has one value at a time.